# VS Code shortcut to move cursor to next parameter in a function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

`CardMeta(2001, 1, 1, "Fruit Card", "Apple", "나비")`

What is the keyboard shorcut to move the mouse cursor from one paramenter to anther while editing.

For instance if i want to edit the valuse of paremeters, how do i jump from one paramenter "Fruit Card" to the start of the next "Apple" one with keyboard shortcut instead of clicking with mouse.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) and the command `moveby.regex`

Define the following key binding

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f6",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": {
      "regex": ", ?",
      "properties": ["next", "end"]
    }
  }
```

If you have complex function arguments like function calls with arguments it goes to these arguments first.

Comment: Try it with this regex: `    "regex": "(?<=\\()|(,\\s?)(?=.*\\))",` it'll hit the first argument from anywhere preceding in the line.  And can be used to move down the page jumping to all the arguments in other functions pretty neatly.

Comment: @Mark the part `(?<=\()` will hit any `(` used in an expression

Comment: Yes, so only those in a string/regex would be a problem - small price to pay for jumping to all parameters, even empty `()` that may need a parameter.  It is fast, so if it goes somewhere you don't want , just trigger again..